# Can't run Groovy test cases from Ant

Tags: ant, groovy, junit

My Ant target looks like this:

```
<target name="junit" depends="compile">
    <junit haltonfailure="true" printsummary="true">
        <classpath>
            <fileset dir="${idea.dir}/lib" includes="junit.jar" />
            <fileset dir="${build.dir}" includes="**" />
        </classpath>
        <formatter type="plain" usefile="true" />
        <batchtest fork="false" todir="${out.dir}">
            <fileset dir="${build.dir}" includes="test_*/*Test.class" />
        </batchtest>
    </junit>
</target>
```

All compiled classes from the project are in `${build.dir}`, as well as all compiled test cases. The latter are within `${build.dir}/test_*` sub folders.

There is one test class `${build.dir}/test_ecs/EntityManagerTest.class`, which apparently is found in `batchtest`. However, Ant gives me this output in the junit report:

```
test_ecs.EntityManagerTest
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: test_ecs.EntityManagerTest
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
    at com.intellij.rt.ant.execution.AntMain2.main(AntMain2.java:30)
```

Now, what I don't understand is: Why is the test case class file found, but then the error says exactly that class is not found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try modifying the `<classpath>..` section like this:

```
<junit ..>
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="${idea.dir}/lib/junit.jar"/>
            <pathelement path="${build.dir}"/>
        </classpath>
```

and see if it runs...

Comment: Great, that fixed it, thank you very much. One question though: Why does it work with `pathelement`, but not with `fileset` in the classpath?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your issue is the classpath declaration:

```
<classpath>
    <fileset dir="${idea.dir}/lib" includes="junit.jar" />
    <fileset dir="${build.dir}" includes="**" />
</classpath>
```

Are your *.class files located in the build directory? Or a subdirectory of the build dir?

By way of example here's my standard junit task:

```
<junit printsummary="yes" haltonfailure="yes">
    <classpath>
        <path refid="test.path"/>
        <pathelement path="${build.dir}/classes"/>
        <pathelement path="${build.dir}/test-classes"/>
    </classpath>
    <formatter type="xml"/>
    <batchtest fork="yes" todir="${build.dir}/test-reports">
        <fileset dir="${test.src.dir}">
            <include name="**/*Test*.java"/>
            <exclude name="**/AllTests.java"/>
        </fileset>
    </batchtest>
</junit>
```

Note the classpath declaration. It includes the path to 3rd party dependency jars, the directory where I compiled my classes to and the directory I compiled my test classes to.